# Deployed my Breeze app to Azure Web Sites and Metadata query fails

Tags: azure, breeze

Just starting off with Breeze and Azure. I downloaded the sample app and added my own controllers. On my local machine it works just fine. When I deploy to my Azure site, I keep getting the following error in the logging section of the page: *Query failed: Metadata query failed for: api/CoreData/Metadata; An error has occurred.*

I have a controller named Products that simply returns a view. The view contains the js calls to my CoreData ApiController. Follows the sample.

The only thing logged on the server is the following:
[image: 500]

At first I was using EF to access data, but have changed to just creating an in-memory object and returning it so as to eliminate db issues.

The URL is http://acapella.azurewebsites.net/products. I've spent quite a bit of time trying to diagnose and research, but feel that I'm overlooking something simple.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I usually start by trying to hit the Web API. Tried this: http://acapella.azurewebsites.net/api/coredata/metadata  Got "An error has occurred" which means the metadata resource was found (else I'd have gotten a 404) and failed. Of course your deployed web.config is configured to hide the error. You'll have to find a way to get more info from your azure site. I know this much .. about Azure

Comment: Btw, it takes several seconds to fail. That suggests an inability to crank up EF and the Db. I'm just guessing though.

Comment: Have you removed all the EF stuff from your project? Sounds like maybe you have a code-first EF model that is trying to generate a local database and failing? Just guessing from your comments and Ward's guesses.

Comment: @Bryant, I do have EF code first and was thinking the same thing about permissions. I created the login/user and assigned proper permissions. When that didn't work, I removed any db call in my controller.

Comment: @Ward I'll have a look at the config and see if I can find a way to surface more information.

Comment: I created a Test controller and am able to access the default data (acapella.azurewebsites.net/api/test/get). Still no luck with metadata, but it's most likely what @Bryant suggested regarding EF. I'm going to keep investigating and will update once I get more info.

Comment: Looks like you have fixed it - what was the problem?

Comment: It's not fixed. The Test controller is just a simple ApiController with no database access.

Comment: I have given up on getting it to work. I'm probably going to switch to SqlCE or something else.

Comment: FYI - SQLCE won't work with Azure.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to have too spend time this weekend trying again from scratch. Some simple test projects or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

An Azure web site is a free, relatively easy way to deploy a Breeze application where you can test it on a variety of mobile devices and experience your app's responsiveness (or lack thereof).

I have had good success pushing a Breeze app to an Azure web site but there were many stumbles including some that looked like yours.

Two thoughts. First, you'll want to turn "Custom errors off" in your Web.config.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

My second recommendation: take a look at [John Papa's post on deploying an MVC Web API app to an Azure web site](http://www.johnpapa.net/publishing-a-web-app-to-windows-azure/). It is excellent. And I know it works.

I hope to have a video on the process very soon.

Comment: Thank you, Ward. I hope to have some time to try that this weekend. I will post any update here.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you can do is return the exception. In your Breeze controller do this:

```
[HttpGet]
public string Metadata()
{
    try
    {
        return _contextProvider.Metadata();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return e.Message + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + e.StackTrace;
    }
}
```

That made it clear to me something was wrong with my connection string. The exception I got was:

```
Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.
```

My connection string locally seemed ok, but the problem was on Azure. My web.release.config had a correct transform, but when publishing, Visual Studio would add another connection string. You can check this by connecting with FTP to your Azure site and looking at your web.config. I fixed it by selecting the correct connection string when publishing:

[image: Publishing to Azure]

After that, there still seem to be two connection strings in my uploaded web.config, but at least it works.